# code for handler in android

Tags: android

In for loop, there is a method which invokes handler.post(). There exists a log statement inside for loop which prints a log message 16 times (indicates that for loop executed for 16 times). Similarly there is one more Log message inside run(), but unfortunately app printing this log message 300 times (approx), which ideally should print only for 16 times. Can some one guide me to understand the mistake?

code snippet is:

```
     do
    {
      final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
      System.out.println("KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK");
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() { 
            System.out.println("IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII");

              // Post again 16ms later.
               boolean booleanHandler= handler.postDelayed(this, 32); 
               System.out.println("******************************"+booleanHandler);
            } });
   }
while(16 times)
```

edit: if condition removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this:

```
//declare like this
private Handler handler = new Handler();

// call in oncreate()
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000); //30sec

//inside this function which u have to run
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {


        handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
    }
};
```

Comment: can i execute handler with in loop?

Comment: ya... u can use in loop also

Comment: this code for :  Actually adding pins to map,then apply animation to pins like all pins should be launch with some animation effect

Answer (score 0):

this is infinite call to the handler, because value of t does not seems t be changed inside your handler

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in variable t. If (t >= 0 && t <= 1.0) is true then your code posts itself in a handler again and again until t is changed. So, if you want exactly 16 executions then you should not call handler.post() inside your Runnable or change t before doing it.

Comment: Sorry,here t value is changing,but its not reflected to our condition

Comment: One more guess: if you change t from another thread then you should consider using 'volatile' key-word - so, you avoid delays with updating value of t by VM.